# Display a php page with ajax

Tags: ajax

I am trying to display contents of a php file on my html page using ajax.

**get_ajay.html**

```
<form action="">
 First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onblur="show users(this.value)">
 </form>

<p>Username: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 

 <script>
function showHint(str) {
var xhttp;
if (str.length == 0) { 
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;
}
 xhttp = newXMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
 }
 };
 xhttp.open("GET", "user.php?u="+str, true);
 xhttp.send();   
}
</script>
```

**user.php**

```
 <?php

echo $_GET["u"];?>
```

It doesn't display the username on my get_ajax.html page.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

get_ajay.html should be get_ajay.php , by default PHP isn't interpreted on HTML pages.